# Output only one possible result looping thru 2 arrays with if-statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays. Each element of which I compare numbers of first array are greater than the seconds' and if it finds (through  `if statement`) any number from first array greater than any number from second array, I `console.log them`. However, there might be more than one coincidence but per one request in need to `console.log` only first result.

Say,
First array has `[0.4,0,6]`
Second array has `[0.5,0.5]`

It produces 2 results since there are two matches. How to get only first one.

My code looks like that:

https://jsfiddle.net/oxpwb0j3/2/

```
const numbers = [0.6,0.4];

for(a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {
     var res_num1 = numbers[a];
   
   const numbers2 = [0.5,0.5];
   
   for(b = 0; b < numbers2.length; b++) {
         var res_num2 = numbers2[b];
       
       if(res_num1 > res_num2){
            console.log(res_num1+" = "+res_num2);
       }
   }
}
```

it outputs:

```
0.6 = 0.5
0.6 = 0.5
```

as I explained in the beginning how to limit to only log the first result like so `0.6 = 0.5`.

I'm new to JS and learning. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add break the first time it met the condition.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

```
const numbers = [0.4,0.6];

for(a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {

   var res_num1 = numbers[a];

   const numbers2 = [0.5,0.5];
 
   for(b = 0; b < numbers2.length; b++) {

      var res_num2 = numbers2[b];

      if(res_num1 > res_num2){

        console.log(res_num1+" = "+res_num2);
        break;

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, yet so simple. Thanks a lot. Never knew about break in loops except switch.

Comment: @Konoha you might need to see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide to get familiar with the language.

Comment: Of course. Official docs seem to be so complicated but yes that's the core point.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use labels

```js
const numbers = [0.4,0.5,0.6];

   for(a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {

     var res_num1 = numbers[a];

     const numbers2 = [0.5,0.5];
     
     outerloop: for(b = 0; b < numbers2.length; b++) {

          var res_num2 = numbers2[b];

          if(res_num1 > res_num2){

            console.log(res_num1+" = "+res_num2);
            break outerloop;
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).